# How can i submitt multiforms generated randomly and dynamically in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on event scheduler project using asp.net MVC where client will see their agendas, agenda will contain different sessions e.g. registeration,lunch,break,workshops etc.

session workshop is two level e.g. there can be more than one workshop at same time and client has to choose which one he wants to attend. each workshop has number of seats and workshop sessions are random and multiple.

i am able to display workshops i.e. radio buttons along with number of seats now what i want is that when a client choose one of the workshop i want to save his selection and update number of seats and if seats are 0 i want to disable that radiobutton. if selection is already made on page load i want to show that as well, below is the code what i have tried and now i have no clue how to save the selection, i am very new to asp.net MVC.

```
if (!ThisSession.Mandatory && ThisSession.SessionOptions != null && ThisSession.SessionOptions.Count > 0)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        foreach (DaySession ThisOption in ThisSession.SessionOptions)
        {
            <div style="width:95%;float:right;" class="OptionNode">
                <input type="radio"/>@ThisOption.Name
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div style="width: 95%; float: right;" class="OptionNode">
    @foreach (string ThisOption in Model)
    {
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="@ThisOption" value="@ThisOption"/>@ThisOption
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btn" />
  </div>
}
```

The point is that you need set the name attribute to work radios as one unit.
Then you have to set the value attribute, so you can find the selected radiobutton in the request or as a parameter.
As parameter:

```
public List<string> _options = new List<string>
{
  "Opt1",
  "Opt2",
  "Opt3"
};

public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(_options);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string options)
{
  return View(_options);
}
```

You can also find the value in the request:

```
string selectedRadio = Request.Params["options"];
```

The name of the parameter has to match with the name attribute of the radios, and the value you get from the parameter or the request will be the value attribute of the selected radio.

Comment: thanks for your reply but as i mentioned above i want to submit on radionbutton selection changed not any submit button plus i already have my model an inner list of options i.e. i have session which then have options and on selection i want to update the number of seats left